# How to scan objects of non primitive types?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a project where I need to scan in a value from a file that is of type "Itinerary" but I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my code:

```
    switch (idChar) {

           case 'B':
              flightNumIn = scanFile.next();
              tripDataIn = scanFile.next();
              baseFareIn = scanFile.nextDouble();
              fareAdjustmentFactorIn = scanFile.nextDouble();
              foodBeveragesIn = scanFile.nextDouble();
              entertainmentIn = scanFile.nextDouble();

              Business bTicket1 = new Business(flightNumIn, tripDataIn, 
                 baseFareIn, fareAdjustmentFactorIn, foodBeveragesIn, 
                 entertainmentIn);

              break;
```

And the actual error:

```
    AirTicketProcessor.java:43: error: incompatible types
              tripDataIn = scanFile.next();
                                        ^
    required: Itinerary
    found:    String
```

Comment: You need to scan for certain data type (like String, int etc.,) and create Itenarary from that. I don't think you can directly scan Itenarary object from console.

Comment: Yes you can I will post answer.

Answer (score 0):

scanFile.next() is returning a String, not an Itinerary. Try System.out.println(scanFile.next()); to get a clue as to what it is.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` reads a `String` but you could add a constructor matching the 'scanned' types to your `Itinerary` class:

```
class Itinerary {
   public Itinerary(String str, int intValue, ...) {
     ...
  }
}
```

and create like so:

```
tripDataIn = new Itinerary(scanFile.next(), scanFile.nextInt(), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you are trying to do is called object serialization. You need to start [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization). That is a great tutorial on how to set up a serializable class. You basically need to make a class called `Itinerary` that implements Serializable. The you will use FileIO to import and export files of that type. A tutorial on the writing out (and loading) can be found [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57). The reason your code did not work was that Scanner is attempting to scan in objects of type String.